# How do I post my login_data to this Xenforo powered forum

Tags: python, python-requests

i'm currently trying to login to a website/forum that uses Xenforo.
I found the post data and made a post request with it, i'm not sure if it works or if im doing it correctly, heres my code:

```
import requests


class Bumper:
    def __init__(self, login_url):
        self.login_url = login_url

    def login(self, username, password):
        login_payload = {'login': username, 'password': password}
        resp = requests.post(url=self.login_url, data=login_payload)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Bumper(login_url="https://www.sythe.org/login").login(username="MyUsername", password="MyPassword")
```

Postdata:

```
login=MyUsername
register=0
password=MyPassword
remember=1
cookie_check=1
_xfToken
redirect=https://www.sythe.org/
```

Website url to login: https://www.sythe.org/login

Answer (score 0):

to fix your issues I would recommend you to add a header to your POST request, modify the `login_payload` and add `requests.session()` *(as your website doesn't let you to login into it if it doesn't find any cookies)*.

All in all your code should look something like this:

```
import requests


class Bumper:
    def __init__(self, login_url):
        self.login_url = login_url

    def login(self, username, password):
        session = requests.session()
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
        login_payload={"login": username,
                    "register": "0", 
                    "password": password, 
                    "remember": "1", 
                    "cookie_check": "1", 
                    "_xfToken": '', 
                    "redirect": "https://www.sythe.org/"
                   }

        session.get(url=self.login_url,headers = headers)
        resp = session.post(url=self.login_url, data=login_payload)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Bumper(login_url="https://www.sythe.org/login").login(username="MyUsername", password="MyPassword")
```

hope this helps

Comment: Okay so now as an example how would I post lets say a reply to a thread/post now that i'm logged in, Here's the post data for posting on a thread

Comment: ```message_html=<p><br></p>
_xfRelativeResolver=https://www.sythe.org/threads/200-000-vouched-buying-all-marketable-pubg-skins-40.3614108/page-6
attachment_hash=88b24cb54e6f6ed025d60b3315cc37d0
last_date=1555432361
last_known_date=1555432361
_xfToken=987811,1555433625,1d4bca87cf2834024a958a0e4aa6bc3a5fd5d189
_xfRequestUri=/threads/3614108/200-000-vouched-buying-all-marketable-pubg-skins-40/page-6
_xfNoRedirect=1
_xfToken=987811,1555433625,1d4bca87cf2834024a958a0e4aa6bc3a5fd5d189
_xfResponseType=json```

Comment: @KaihanHakimi Well I don't have an account on the website so I can't really tell

Comment: it's a xenforo forum, do you have any clue? thats the postdata and etc.